# Get environment variables in .Net Core / UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core

I try to migrate our .Net 4 desktop application to an UWP App, which is a hard task without documentation like MSDN. Know I have all methods to connect to the existing Webservice, but the used methods return nothing.

```
var envVars = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();
var host = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME");
var user = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME");
var userDnsDomain = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDNSDOMAIN");
```

GetEnvironmentVariables has a count of 0 and the old methods from .Net don't exist anymore:

```
var host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
var user = Environment.UserName;
```

I need the name of the computer, the logged in username and the domain.

Is there a trick or an alternative?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.system.user

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution:

```
var users = await User.FindAllAsync(UserType.LocalUser);
var user = (string) await users.FirstOrDefault().GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.AccountName);
var domain = "";
var host = "";

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
{
    var domainWithUser = (string) await users.FirstOrDefault().GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.DomainName);
    domain = domainWithUser.Split('\\')[0];
    user = domainWithUser.Split('\\')[1];
}

var host = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames().First(x => x.Type == HostNameType.DomainName).DisplayName.Split('.')[0];
```

Comment: Hmm. In `.NET Core` (at least as implemented in .NETStandard 1.6), the `System.Net.NetworkInformation` does not contain a `GetHostNames()`.  What version of `.NET Core` are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is more of a **warning**.

1. You cannot query environment variables ad-hoc in UWP, not even with PInvoke
2. You can query the user's information, but there's absolutely no guarantee the `User` API will work for multiple user-types, so you need to defensively code against null values. **I have no idea why this API is so unreliable**.

Here's a sample MainPage and a screenshot showing all the data returned as blank.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App_1
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            GetUserInfo();
        }

        public static async void GetUserInfo()
        {
            var users = await User.FindAllAsync(UserType.LocalUser);
            var user = await users.FirstOrDefault().GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.AccountName);
            var user_count = users.Count;
            var AccountName =
                await users[0].GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.AccountName);
            var DisplayName =
                await users[0].GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.DisplayName);
            var DomainName =
                await users[0].GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.DomainName);
            var FirstName =
                await users[0].GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.FirstName);
            var GuestHost =
                await users[0].GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.GuestHost);
            var LastName =
                await users[0].GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.LastName);
            var PrincipalName =
                await users[0].GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.PrincipalName);
            var ProviderName =
                await users[0].GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.ProviderName);
            var SessionInitiationProtocolUri =
                await users[0].GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.SessionInitiationProtocolUri);
            var User_Type = users[0].Type;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: all_null]